# C - CS50 pset1 Mario Pyramid challenge

Tags: c, cs50

I've googled and read posts on stacks, but still don't know where my codes goes wrong on this problem set... it just keep asking typing "height". After typed height in, it doesn't go to next step, seems to stuck in an infinite loop.

Brain melting.

Please help to point out where my codes goes wrong. Thx a lot.

```
 #include <cs50.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     int height;
     do
     {
        printf ("height: ");
        height = get_int();
     }        
     while (height >= 0 || height <= 23);

     for (int loop = 0; loop <= height; loop++)
     {
         for (int space = height - 1 - loop; space > 0; space--)
             printf("  ");


         for (int hash = 2 + loop; hash < height; hash++)
             printf("#");

         printf("\n");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use scanf() instead?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `do {...} while (height < 0 || height > 23);`? You want to ask the height again if the user input a value outside the boundaries, I presume. Also, does 'get_int' manage the cases where the user enters something other the `int`s?

Comment: @Bob__ Thanks so much, you got the point. I should set the inequality more carefully, or, it will be like an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here, in the do while loop you are giving the condition that loop should continue whatever you put the height because every number is either `>=0` or `<=23`.

Instead change the condition to `while(height<0||height>23)`